# Error: Must declare a named package because this compilation unit is associated to the named module '*******'

Tags: java, eclipse-photon

I was trying to open a program I made before but for some reason the following error always appeared:
Must declare a named package because this compilation unit is associated to the named module '********'

[image]

Comment: I understand the message as "you must use a non-default package for your classes". Create a package, move classes to it, and declare a package in the file

Comment: @ernest_k Thanks so much! It finally works now!

Answer (score 2):

An easy solution to this problem is to delete the **module-info.java** file present on your *Project Explorer* tab. Eclipse created this by default, and also, removing this will not affect any functionality of your program. So, go for it...

Answer (score 0):

I created a new package, and moved the error classes from the default package to new one, then the error disappeared !

Source: [@ernest_k's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51803456/error-must-declare-a-named-package-because-this-compilation-unit-is-associated/68096330#comment90563029_51803456)